# implementing javascript inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I am trying to understand inheritance in javascript

```
function baseClass(name) {
   this.name = name;
   this.getName = function() {
       return this.name;
   }
}



function subClass(id, company){
       baseClass.call(this);
       this.id = id;
       this.company = company;
       this.toString = function() {
           return name + "\n" + this.id + "\n" + this.company; 
       }  
   }



subClass.prototype = Object.create(baseClass);
   var s = new subClass();
   s.toString();  //here the name property from the baseClass is not displayed.
```

How do correctly implement inheritance (classical / prototypical)

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020577/proper-prototypal-inheritance) of 45 minutes ago. Also, forget about classical, since EcmaScript (javascript) is a prototypal language.

Comment: "classical / prototypical" - which one do you mean?

Comment: There is no _classical_ as JavaScript is a **prototypal** language...

Comment: Fix the typos in your code: `Object.Create(baseClass)` should be `Object.create(baseclass)` and `var s = new SubClass();` should be `var s = new subClass()`

Comment: [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) is an interesting article with a simple javascript inheritance implementation from John Resig that might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there are two minor issues:

- Casing matters in JavaScript. [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) needs to be lowercased, and your function names don't match (`subClass` vs `SubClass`). Usually, constructor function names are uppercased.
- Use the property `this.name` (which is inherited) instead of the variable `name` (which is undefined) - see [Javascript: Do I need to put this.var for every variable in an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13418669/1048572)

> How do correctly implement inheritance

Move the methods (which don't need to privileged, there are no local variables in the constructor scope) on the prototype objects. And let `SubClass.prototype` inherit from `BaseClass.prototype`, not from the `BaseClass` function.

```
function BaseClass(name) {
   this.name = name;
}
BaseClass.prototype.getName = function() {
   return this.name;
};

function SubClass(id, company){
    BaseClass.call(this);
    this.id = id;
    this.company = company;
}
SubClass.prototype = Object.create(BaseClass.prototype);
SubClass.prototype.toString = function() {
   return this.name + "\n" + this.id + "\n" + this.company; 
};
```

> `new SubClass().toString()` does not display the name property from the baseClass

You're calling the constructor without any arguments. The `id`, `company` and `name` properties will have the `undefined` value. Also, your `SubClass` doesn't even have a parameter for the `name`, and it doesn't pass anything to the `BaseClass` constructor invocation.

Comment: `var s = new SubClass()` also need to be lowercased as `var s = new subClass()`